# If - elif - else statement

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=27
b=16
if a > b:
    print('a is greater than b')

elif a > b + 10:
    print('a is greater than b by 10')
elif a == b:
    print('a is equal to b')
else:
    print('a is less than b')
```

The above is the line of code that i used. In this only the 2nd line

```
print('a is greater than b by 10')
```

is not working as i thought rather it throws the output of

```
(if a > b:
    print('a is greater than b')
```

why is that so. since the input of `A` is greater than `B` by `10` why it is not providing the output of that condition?

Comment: because, if a > b + 10, then a > b too. Do you think it would make sense to... say, _switch_ the order, maybe? Think about it.

Comment: 1st. You are not clear on what you want. 2nd: Output for the code is `a is greater than b`. Please be more specific on what you intend to do.

Comment: Pleae make your question clearer. It's not entirely clear what you intend to do. Do you want both conditions to be checked? Or do you only want to output "A is greater than B by 10" ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using if - elif - else. At first, your code will check if the *if* condition is fulfilled. If it is fulfilled, it will run the code in the if block. If the condition is not fulfilled, only then it will check the elif conditions. In your case A is greater than B. So, the **if** condition is fulfilled. It will not check the `elif a > b + 10` condition.

If you want to check that condition first (you want the output "a is greater than b by 10", which seems like what you might actually want), you can change your code to the following:

```
a=27
b=16
if a > b + 10:
    print('a is greater than b by 10')
elif a > b:
    print('a is greater than b')
elif a == b:
    print('a is equal to b')
else:
    print('a is less than b')
```

**Output:**

> a is greater than b by 10

If you want both conditions to be checked, you can use two if statements. The code will be like the following:

```
a=27
b=16
if a > b + 10:
    print('a is greater than b by 10')
elif a > b:
    print('a is greater than b')
elif a == b:
    print('a is equal to b')
else:
    print('a is less than b')
```

**Output:**

> a is greater than b by 10
>
> a is greater than b

If you want one to be checked only if the other is fulfilled, try nesting those if statements.

```
a=27
b=16
if a > b:
    if a > b + 10:
        print('a is greater than b by 10')
    else:
        print('a is greater than b')
elif a == b:
    print('a is equal to b')
else:
    print('a is less than b')
```

**Output:**

> a is greater than b by 10

P.S. You should try to learn more about the if-elif-else statements and how they actually work. You can find some excellent tutorials online which will be able to help you.

Comment: yo pal, your first answer and the second one are both the same line of code. Then how the first one exhibits only one output as(a is greater than b by 10) but the 2nd one with the same line of code exhibits two output i.e(a is greater than b by 10) and (a is greater than b) also????. Third line of code i can understand that you were using nested if condition. So overall thank you Das.

Comment: For the second ans you have stated to use 2 if conditions, but you didn't.

Comment: Das, i've tried as you informed to use 2 if conditions. It works. Thank you.